# Getting this weird error in zsh shell 'top: failed tty set: Interrupted system call'

Tags: linux, terminal, top, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**nano** works fine if I try to run in the background

```
[~]$ nano &
[1] 739
[~]$
[1]  + 739 suspended (tty output)  nano
[~]$ fg
[1]  + 739 continued  nano
```

But if I try to run **top** in this way then it shows an error:

```
[~]$ top &
[1] 810
[1]  + 810 suspended (signal)  top
[~]$ fg
[1]  + 810 continued  top

top: failed tty set: Interrupted system call
```

I tried another way, but again the same result

```
[~]$ top &
[1] 832
[1]  + 832 suspended (signal)  top
[~]$ jobs
[1]  + suspended (signal)  top
[~]$ fg %1
[1]  + 832 continued  top

top: failed tty set: Interrupted system call
```

I'm using **zsh** shell on **WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux)**. I'll be obliged if someone can help me with this error.

Comment: That's just a bug in `top` -- it fails to handle the `EINTR` error from `tcsetattr(3)` -- which happens because of the `SIGTTOU` signal it gets when trying to change the terminal attributes while in background.

Comment: Starting full screen programs like `nano` or `top` in background is weird; they are immediately stopped (by a `SIGTTIN` signal -- when they try to read from the tty, or by a `SIGTTOU` signal, when try to change the tty parameters). Many programs handle that badly. Why are you trying to run them like that?

Comment: Just saw it in a tutorial. It was for educational purpose

Comment: I also noticed if I ran with 'sudo top &' and then 'fg', it works fine before prompting user password

Comment: `sudo` probably handles it better. Many people assume that `tcsetattr(3)` cannot fail, unless there's some unrecoverable error like not being called on a tty. You can submit a bug report about it -- they should probably retry the `tcsetattr(3)` if it failed with `EINTR`.

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with zsh or wsl -- the `top` from procps package will behave the same no matter what shell is called from.

Comment: alright, I guess I should ignore it